# Problema al convertir String de SharedPreferences a double para sacar promedio

Tags: java, android-studio, sharedpreferences

Estoy tratando de usar unos datos almacenados en SharedPreferences pero luego de llamarlos, al tratar de convertirlos a double o integer no me deja ejecutar la actividad (se cierra inmediatamente). Cuando comento este bloque

```
"dAntIzq1= parseDouble(AntIzq1);
 dAntIzq2= parseDouble(AntIzq2);
 dAntIzq3= parseDouble(AntIzq3);"
```

que es donde los trato de convertir para ejecutar la operacion, si se ejecuta la actividad pero obviamente no me saca el promedio de los numeros.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

```
public class envio extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    TextView tvAntIzqM;
    String AntIzq1, AntIzq2, AntIzq3;
    double dAntIzq1, dAntIzq2, dAntIzq3;
    double dAntIzqM;
    String sAntIzqM;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_envio);

        prefs = getSharedPreferences("com.bmnigom", MODE_PRIVATE);

        AntIzq1=prefs.getString("strAntIzq1", "0");
        AntIzq2=prefs.getString("strAntIzq2", "0");
        AntIzq3=prefs.getString("strAntIzq3", "0");

        dAntIzq1= parseDouble(AntIzq1);
        dAntIzq2= parseDouble(AntIzq2);
        dAntIzq3= parseDouble(AntIzq3);

        dAntIzqM=(dAntIzq1+dAntIzq2+dAntIzq3)/3;

        sAntIzqM =String.valueOf(dAntIzqM);

        tvAntIzqM=findViewById(R.id.tvAntIzqM);

        tvAntIzqM.setText(sAntIzqM);

    }
}
```

creo que este es el error:

```
2020-07-08 23:12:11.203 2043-2043/com.bmnigom.startest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.bmnigom.startest, PID: 2043
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bmnigom.startest/com.bmnigom.startest.envio}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{b5c6b77 VFED..CL. ........ 632,0-868,136 #7f07006c app:id/etAntIzq1}"
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3961)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2386)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{b5c6b77 VFED..CL. ........ 632,0-868,136 #7f07006c app:id/etAntIzq1}"
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
        at com.bmnigom.startest.envio.onCreate(envio.java:132)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8086)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8074)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3755)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3961) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2386) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
```

Tengo 3 actividades en las que capturo los datos. En cada una realizo 3 pasos, primero capturo el dato de un EditText, luego convierto el dato a un string, para posteriormente enviarlo a un archivo de preferencias donde voy guardando los datos.

```
@Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_rep1);

       ani1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAntIzq1);
       
       sani1= String.valueOf(ani1) ;

       botonRep1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRep1);
       botonRep1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {

               prefs=getSharedPreferences("com.bmnigom",MODE_PRIVATE);
               SharedPreferences.Editor editor= prefs.edit();
               editor.putString("strAntIzq1",String.valueOf(sani1));
               editor.commit();

               Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), rep2.class);
               startActivity(intent);
           }
       });
   }
```

Comment: Si deseas ser desarrollador Android, el uso del LogCat es indispensable, agrega que error se muestra al cerrarse la aplicaciòn, saludos.

Comment: Hola Jorge, muchas gracias por tu consejo. El error que aparece es: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@11c5514 pero no he podido encontrar la solucion, saludos.

Comment: El error se produce en otra parte, agrega el mensaje de error completo por favor.

Comment: Luego de quitar el filtro de LogCat pude encontrar estas lineas, pero aun no logro encontrar como solucionarlo, muchas gracias

Comment: Agrega por favor como guardas los valores ,  ahí se encuentra el problema @NicolasGomez

Comment: Jorge, muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Ahí puse el código de como tomo los datos, la verdad en medio de lo poco que se no veo el problema. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Acabo de darme cuenta de que no esta tomando el valor del EditText

Comment: Debes usar  getText().toString(); como indico en la respuesta @NicolasGomez

Answer (score 1):

El problema se describe aquí:

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
> "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{b5c6b77 VFED..CL.
> ........ 632,0-868,136 #7f07006c app:id/etAntIzq1}"

Se debe a que los valores que guardas en las preferencias no son numericos y al obtenerlos en este punto y tratas de usar `parseDouble()` se provocara el problema:

```
    AntIzq1=prefs.getString("strAntIzq1", "0");
    AntIzq2=prefs.getString("strAntIzq2", "0");
    AntIzq3=prefs.getString("strAntIzq3", "0");

    dAntIzq1= parseDouble(AntIzq1);
    dAntIzq2= parseDouble(AntIzq2);
    dAntIzq3= parseDouble(AntIzq3);
```

Si los valores los obtienes de `EditText`, debes usar `.getText().toString();`

---

De acuerdo a tu código debería ser:

```
@Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_rep1);

       ani1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAntIzq1);
       
       //sani1= String.valueOf(ani1) ;

       botonRep1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRep1);
       botonRep1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {

               prefs=getSharedPreferences("com.bmnigom",MODE_PRIVATE);
               SharedPreferences.Editor editor= prefs.edit();
               editor.putString("strAntIzq1", ani1.getText().toString());
               editor.commit();

               Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), rep2.class);
               startActivity(intent);
           }
       });
   }
```

Comment: Hola Jorge, cambié el código como me dijiste, pero aún sigo con el mismo problema. De hecho, al poner un Toast no me muestra un valor numérico. Creo que el problema es al obterner el valor del EditText (que es numérico). Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Si los valores los obtienes de EditText, debes usar .getText().toString();

Comment: Hola Jorge, muchas gracias por tu ayuda. He usado .getText().to.String(); y sigue sin funcionar. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

veo en tu código...dAntIzq1= parseDouble(AntIzq1); la sintaxis correcta es: dAntIzq1 = Double.parseDouble(AntIzq1); buen día espero te funcione, sino comenta y veo que más podría ser.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias. De hecho así la tenía originalmente, pero tampoco me funcionó.

Comment: Desde mi ignorancia te pregunto...Y si imprimes por consola el valor de tu variable String AntIzq1 justo después de asignarla...AntIzq1=prefs.getString("strAntIzq1", "0"); System.out.println("AntIzq1 = " + AntIzq1); y ves si lo que estás recibiendo es realmente un double y no otro numero (haciendo debug) por equivalencia de algún texto? te manda alguna excepción como java.lang.NumberFormatException?

Comment: Hola Gustavo, también soy nuevo, en el LogCat me aparece: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@f2a5b26. Pero aun no se como solucionarlo. muchas gracias!